# What is the best way to index SOLR document with files?

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR to index some forum posts, but some of the posts they have attachment to it. I currently have the index only looking at the forum posts but I would like to also add the content of the attachment to the index.

I saw that I can use Tika to index document (PDF, Word, etc). Is it possible to add the document to the same index I currently have? is this ok, or should I make a new index for the documents?

My current index has the following fields:

Topic_Title, Topic_Body

Could I make something like this if the post has an attachment?

Topic_Title, Topic_Body, Topic_Document

So Topic_Document will be the attached file if the topic post has any attachment?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is. You can just define the `Topic_Document` field in the schema, then (when indexing) if they have an attachement, use Tika to index the attachment's content. You don't need a new core/collection for the attachments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was not sure if I should just add the documents to the same index or make a new index for the documents.